# Adicionar o mesmo com o evento click

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho no meu código wpf um listbox com o nome de "lstBox" (deixei invisível), e dentro dele um listBoxItem com uma label e um textbox . Fora do listbox , na mesma window tenho um botão " adicionar item " (ao clicar ficaria visível o listbox). Gostaria de que a cada clicada neste botão ele criasse um novo listboxItem com a mesma cara do que ja criei no código wpf dentro do lstBox e esta apenas invisível. 
Alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox
        Name="lstBox"
        Margin="0,191,51,46">
        <ListBoxItem
            Name="lstboxitem"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="78"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="167"
            Background="#FFE8B0B0"/>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Margin="664,206,76,396" Click="Button_Click_1" 
            />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Poderia postar um trecho do código utilizado para uma maior visualização do problema?

Comment: editei a pergunta postando tambem o codigo xaml que tenho feito.
Preciso que ao clicar no botao com o evento click, meu listbox tenha mais um listboxitem exatamente igual ao que ja tenho criado no xaml

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um escopo no Visual Basic para você ter uma ideia:

```
Sub New()
meuListBox.Items.Add("Meu item fixo!")
End Sub

Dim meuItem = meuListBox.Items(0)

Public Sub buttonClick(sender as Object, e as RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
meuListBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
meuListBox.Items.Add(meuItem)
End Sub
```

Vou comentar tudo aqui antes, para que possa esclarecer algumas dúvidas:

> O `Sub New()` é a **inicialização** da classe/tela, usei-o para adicionar o item padrão.
>
> O zero em `meuListBox.Items(0)` indica que estamos pegando o **primeiro item**, já que a contagem do index começa em 0.
>
> Ao escrever `meuListBox.Items.Add(meuItem)`, estamos **adicionando** o primeiro item da lista (supondo que ele já exista).

Em `meuItem` obtemos o primeiro item do seu ListBox, e no clique do botão adicionamos esse item.
Nota-se que o usual seria ter uma classe, sendo ela o `DataContext`da sua tela, atribuindo o `ListBox.ItemSource` a uma propriedade dessa classe, disparando o `PropertyChanged` para as alterações na tela. Outra observação é a `Margin` que você atribuiu ao botão, o seu `Grid` deveria conter linhas (`RowDefinition`) e colunas (`ColumnDefinition`), assim normalizando ou até dispensando a `Margin` do botão.

Deixarei abaixo alguns links importantes para que você aperfeiçoe seus conhecimentos com o WPF:

1. [WPF-Tutorial.com](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/about-wpf/what-is-wpf/)
2. [Josh Smith On WPF](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/)
3. [WPF Unleashed, de Adam Nathan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917) (se tiver oportunidade de ler esse livro, vale muito a pena!)

Dê uma boa atenção à parte onde fala sobre `DataBinding`, pois ela é crucial ao desenvolvimento com WPF.